# How to guarantee the execution of a loop when process/app is being killed?

Tags: android

My application does the following suite of actions when it fetches the user's schedule from the server:

- stores it into a database (ormlite)
- removes all local notifications set via alarmmanager
- creates new local notifications for the entries in the schedule
- removes all calendar events associated with the entries
- creates new calendar events associated with the entries.

This takes 2-4 seconds depending on how big the schedule is.

However, if the user kills the application from the task window, it gets eliminated immediately, in the middle of a loop, doing any of these.
This means that half of the entries can be entered in the database, half - not.
Or half of the notifications/calendar events will be cancelled/created, the other half - not.

I tried a lot of stuff

1. Using `IntentService` - it gets killed along with the activity (because they belong to the same process)
2. Using a `Service` with `android:process=":remote"` making the service belong to another process, but then, as it turns out, both processes get killed
3. Using a `Service` with `android:process=":remote"` and then having it return `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` on `onStartCommand`, but it gets killed immediately again, and then it starts from top.

The only thing I still havent tried is to `startForeground` using a notification, but this seems to be a very brute force way of solving this problem, and I am still not sure if I am guaranteed that this process will remain alive, even if the app gets killed.

Ok, so maybe I add some transactions to the DB operations and let the DB roll them back if they get interrupted. But what about the local notifications and the calendar events, not to mention - I want to know how to solve this problem for all kinds of cases.

Comment: Well, you'd also have to handle the case if someone decides to rip the battery out mid-transaction.  I think you either have to handle an error case in which the transaction was never complete, or let the notifications roll.

Comment: wow that is even more extreme case I never thought of. Unfortunately I don't understand what do you mean with the second sentence

Comment: Agree with DeeV. Also, you can help your case by making an incrementally more efficient system. There should be only one `AlarmManager` event, and replacing that event with a fresh one if needed takes one IPC call. Having one `AlarmManager` event per entry in the schedule is wasteful. When you get control for the nearest event, set up the next `AlarmManager` event. "what do you mean with the second sentence" -- I presume DeeV means that you need to detect, when your process next starts, that you had not yet completed the work, identify what still needs to be done, and do it.

Comment: Detecting what part of the job had been done seems like a huge job, I can't think of an easy way to do this. What do you usually do in this case?

Comment: Yes, this is true, however, there is a lot of code and I cannot post it here, so I revert my last question

Comment: @J.K.  Sorry.  What I meant was, you either have to handle the error, or let whatever bugs would occur happen if they aren't too debilitating (I assumed in this case that the notifications would be out of sync with the actual calendar).  One thing I can think that would help is do the important tasks first (storing the information), then doing the less important tasks last (syncing the alarmmanagers).  That way, at least you can recover when the application is restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Service#onTaskRemoved(Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved%28android.content.Intent%29) is called when the user swipes your task out of recents.  You can do something in that method, but I don't know what would happen if you tried to wait for something else to finish.

You already mentioned [transactions](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#Transactions) for the DB.  Other data stores generally aren't transactional.  You'd have to layer your own transactions on top of it.  A crude solution would be to write a separate log file containing calendar events about to be written, write them to the calendar, then delete the log.  If the log exists when the app starts, delete any calendar events that are in it.

Comment: So Maybe I write a flag there, then at the next app start I check for that flag and if it says system has been interrupted, I delete/cancel everything and download it anew?

Comment: @J.K. Maybe.  It might be worth experimenting to see what happens if `onTaskRemoved` waits for a background thread to finish.  The Android framework might detect it and force close your app after some time.  Then again, maybe not.  (But even if it works, it might stop working in the future.)

Comment: Is this called if someone force stops the app from the system?  That seems to be what the question is dealing with.

Comment: @DeeV I don't think so.  But I assumed that by "task window," the OP meant the recent task list.